# Filter specific records and earlier using window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have the dataframe like

| name | time | statut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | in |
| A | 2 | out |
| A | 3 | in |
| A | 4 | out |
| A | 5 | in |
| B | 1 | in |
| B | 4 | in |
| B | 7 | out |
| B | 18 | in |

I just want to get for each group the last time that I have `statut` = "out" and the row after. Like this:

| name | time | statut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | out |
| A | 5 | in |
| B | 7 | out |
| B | 18 | in |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a couple of window functions. However, the function which uses the window is not very simple.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', 1, 'in'),
     ('A', 2, 'out'),
     ('A', 3, 'in'),
     ('A', 4, 'out'),
     ('A', 5, 'in'),
     ('B', 1, 'in'),
     ('B', 4, 'in'),
     ('B', 7, 'out'),
     ('B', 18, 'in'),
     ('B', 19, 'in'),
     ('C', 1, 'in')],
    ['name', 'time', 'statut']
)
w_max_out = W.partitionBy('name').orderBy(F.col('statut') != 'out', F.desc('time'))
w_lead = W.partitionBy('name').orderBy(F.desc('time'))
df = df.withColumn('_lead', F.lead('time').over(w_lead))
df = df.withColumn('_max_out', F.max(F.when(F.col('statut') == 'out', F.col('time'))).over(w_max_out))
df = df.filter('(_max_out = time) or (_max_out = _lead)').drop('_max_out', '_lead')
```

Result:

```py
df.show()
# +----+----+------+
# |name|time|statut|
# +----+----+------+
# |   A|   4|   out|
# |   A|   5|    in|
# |   B|   7|   out|
# |   B|  18|    in|
# +----+----+------+
```

Result before the last filter line:

```py
# +----+----+------+-----+--------+
# |name|time|statut|_lead|_max_out|
# +----+----+------+-----+--------+
# |   A|   4|   out|    3|       4|
# |   A|   2|   out|    1|       4|
# |   A|   5|    in|    4|       4|
# |   A|   3|    in|    2|       4|
# |   A|   1|    in| null|       4|
# |   B|   7|   out|    4|       7|
# |   B|  19|    in|   18|       7|
# |   B|  18|    in|    7|       7|
# |   B|   4|    in|    1|       7|
# |   B|   1|    in| null|       7|
# |   C|   1|    in| null|    null|
# +----+----+------+-----+--------+
```